# XSL variable tag name if condition is met

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below XML that I need to transform:

**XML**

```
<CONTENT>
    <DATA TYPE="NODE">
        <ITEM DESC="ENTITY" VALUE="Y"></ITEM>
        <ITEM DESC="REQUEST" VALUE="Y"></ITEM>
    </DATA>
    <ITEM TYPE="INFO"></ITEM>
    <ITEM TYPE="REQ"></ITEM>
    <TAG DESC="FLAG1"></TAG>
    <TAG DESC="FLAG2"></TAG>
    <INFO TYPE="USAGE"></INFO>
</CONTENT>
```

The criteria is for every element having `TYPE={name}` rename the tag name by `{name} of the TYPE` and have as `DESC` the previous tag name as shown below:

**Expected XML**

```
<CONTENT>
    <NODE DESC="DATA">
        <ITEM DESC="ENTITY" VALUE="Y"></ITEM>
        <ITEM DESC="REQUEST" VALUE="Y"></ITEM>
    </NODE>
    <INFO DESC="ITEM"></INFO>
    <REQ DESC="ITEM"></REQ>
    <TAG DESC="FLAG1"></TAG>
    <TAG DESC="FLAG2"></TAG>
    <USAGE DESC="INFO"></USAGE>
</CONTENT>
```

I have below working XSL from previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72580288/808891) but to make it work for this scenario I have to map for each different type, I'm trying to get a generic solution that covers everything with a `TYPE={name}`:

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="*[@TYPE='NODE']">
        <NODE DESC="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='TYPE')]|node()" />          
        </NODE>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@TYPE='INFO']">
        <INFO DESC="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='TYPE')]|node()" />
        </INFO>
    </xsl:template>

    (...)

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "tag name".  Only elements and attribute have names. In fact, there are no tags in XSLT at all. XSLT works on the parsed XML tree. Tags exist only in the original markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[@TYPE]">
    <xsl:element name="{@TYPE}">
        <xsl:attribute name="DESC">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```